# Bash ignoring my condition : if [[ $variable < 10 ]]

Tags: bash, if-statement, terminal, conditional-statements

I have a simple bash script where a file's content is copied to file A if the number of line is inferior to 10, otherwise the content is copied to file B

here the code :

```
# File A and B are created before, since I'm in a loop
# file content is different each time. I add it either to A or B corresponding the matching.
# I know I could use wc -l directly on the file too but I don't think the problem came from
# it since i've tested both.

let nblines=$(cat file | wc -l)

if [[ $nblines < 10 ]]; then
  cat file >> A
else
  cat file >> B
fi
```

The problem is that This work on my terminal and in the script but not always. I have content file in wrong destination file. here what I get from A and B :

```
# "nombre de ligne" is number of lines

test@test:~$ cat A
7 nombre de lignes
7 nombre de lignes
7 nombre de lignes
5 nombre de lignes
5 nombre de lignes
6 nombre de lignes
6 nombre de lignes
6 nombre de lignes
5 nombre de lignes
5 nombre de lignes
76 nombre de lignes
77 nombre de lignes
test@test:~$ cat B
114 nombre de lignes
102 nombre de lignes
131 nombre de lignes
121 nombre de lignes
121 nombre de lignes
105 nombre de lignes
105 nombre de lignes
120 nombre de lignes
120 nombre de lignes
102 nombre de lignes
102 nombre de lignes
9 nombre de lignes
104 nombre de lignes
104 nombre de lignes
105 nombre de lignes
105 nombre de lignes
102 nombre de lignes
102 nombre de lignes
102 nombre de lignes
102 nombre de lignes
109 nombre de lignes
105 nombre de lignes
105 nombre de lignes
```

Does someone know where the problem could come from ?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Hint: If you want to capture the output of a tool (e.g. for posting it on the web), setting `LC_ALL=en_EN` makes the output appear in english locale.

Comment: A good idea, if you want to check whether a file has less than 10 lines is to use `head -n 10 file | wc -l` instead of `cat file | wc -l` (or `wc -l < file`) to end `wc` earlier if it can be determined that the file has 10 lines or more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<` performs a string comparison. To perform a numerical comparison, use `-lt`:

```
if [ "$nblines" -lt 10 ]; then
```

It's up to you whether you want to use `[[` or `[` here (they should do the same) but note that `[[` are not specified by POSIX so your script will be less portable. In this case, it should be unnecessary to quote your variable but it's a good habit to get into anyway.

In bash, you can use `((` and `))` for a more familiar syntax when dealing with numbers:

```
if (( nblines < 10 )); then
```

You don't need to use `$` before the variable name because in an arithmetic context, any characters will be assumed to refer to a variable.

By the way, why are you using `let`? Try `nblines=$(wc -l < file)` (saves a useless use of `cat` as well).

Answer (score 1):

Use `-lt` in `if`

```
let nblines=$(cat file | wc -l)

if [[ $nblines -lt 10 ]]; then
  cat file >> A
else
  cat file >> B
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if [ $nblines -lt 10 ]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

why not

```
[[ $(wc -l < file) -lt 10 ]] && cat file >> A || cat file >> B
```

or

```
[[ $(wc -l < file) -lt 10 ]] && x=A || x=B
cat file >> "$x"
```